# How can I fix LNK2019 error with libsndfile?

Tags: c++, c++11, openal, libsndfile

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State

```
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _sf_open referenced in function "private: unsigned int __thiscall SoundBuffer::AddSoundEffect(char const *)" (?AddSoundEffect@SoundBuffer@@AAEIPBD@Z)    Engines4    D:\xxx\xxxx\sound\PhysicsEngine\Engines4\SoundBuffer.obj
```

1
and three more similar LNK2019

I have done Properties >> General >> Additional Library Directories
Debug >> Project Properties >> Configuration Properties >> C/C++ >> ,General >> Additional Include Directories

Installed the library `libsndfile-1.0.25-w64-setup.exe` file of libsndfile.
I have exited, clean, and rebuild many times!
And VS keeps crying...

Comment: Did you add the library to the `Linker->Input -> Additional Dependencies` setting? I see you setting the include and linker path but not actually linking with the library.

Comment: did you include sndfile.h import? - stdio.h or for any reason also if its C++ cstdio import too?

Comment: @drescherjm This is what it looks like SDL2.lib
SDL2_image.lib
SDL2main.lib
SDL2test.lib
glew32.lib
glew32s.lib
opengl32.lib
OpenAL32.lib
libsndfile-1.lib

Comment: @SamuelMarchant I did include sndfile.h, the program was working fine yesterday, it decided to die today :((

Comment: Odd anyhow, but i notice your in windows so should .obj (i know thats compiler output of the binaries) be an exe or a dll  when run, is the error function line in the same file as the import? (...external symbol...) LNK usually refers to a dll in win.

Comment: @SamuelMarchant Thanks a lot, I fixed by LNK2019 by restarting my PC, should have done that before wasting many valuable hours. I really hate this, hope it doesn't come back and bite me. Thank you so much for you time ! PS: it happens to me sometimes.